# python: glob, loops and local variables

Tags: python, loops, glob

My python script loops over many filles in the directory and performs some operations on each of the file, storing results for each of the file in specific variables, defined for each file, using exec() function:

```
# consider all filles within the current dirrectory, having pdb extension
pdb_list = glob.glob('*.pdb')
#make a list of the filles 
list=[]
# loop over the list and make some operation with each file
for pdb in pdb_list:
        # take file name w/o its extension
        pdb_name=pdb.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ]
        # save file_name of the file
        list.append(pdb_name)
        #set variable u_{pdb_name}, which will be accosiated with some function that do something on the corresponded file
        exec(f'u_{pdb_name} = Universe(pdb)')
        exec(f'print("This is %s computed from %s" % (u_{pdb_name}, pdb_name))')
        # plot a graph using matplot liv
        # exec(f'plt.savefig("rmsd_traj_{pdb_name}.png")')
```

Basically in my file-looping scripts I tend to use exec(f'...') when I need to save a new variable consisted of the part of some existing variable (like a name of the current file, u_{pdb_name})
Is it possible to do similar taks with the names of variavles but avoiding constantly exec() ?

Comment: So you want do you do with those variables? It seems that you could store all those values in a dictionary with the variable names as key

Comment: If you use a class you could use the function setattr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
lst = []
universes = {}
# loop over the list and make some operation with each file
for pdb in pdb_list:
    # take file name w/o its extension
    pdb_name = pdb.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
    # save file_name of the file
    lst.append(pdb_name)
    key = f'u_{pdb_name}'
    universes[key] = Universe(pdb)
    print(f"This is {key} computed from {pdb_name}")
```

To access some value, just do:

```
universes[key]  # where key is the variable name
```

If you want to iterate over all keys and values, do:

```
for key, universe in universes.items():
    print(key)
    print(universe.some_function())
```

Comment: thank you, it works very well! one question - is it possible to further use dictionary in order that I could use all stored variables inside of another for loop (of the same script)? For example if I need carry out some further operations with each or ALL of the elements of dictionary, for example:                           for el in universes: print(el) # this print element correctly el.some_function() # it does not work, telling that el is str but not the requisted obtject of some_function()

Comment: @MaîtreRenard This is because your are iterating over the keys. I updated the answer with something that may help you.

Comment: Right, and would it be possible to create new variables, using the names of stored variables: contained the universes[key] (in the second loop) or key (in the second)? In the simmilar manner what I have implemented in my first post : exec(f'lala_{key} = Some_another_function(pdb)')         meaning that I would like to create a new variable begining with new world "lala" and then adding suffix of the existing {key}